# How to change the height of option?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code. The problem is there are 25 options which makes the options list very long. I want to limit the height of the option and show only 5 then let the user use a vertical scroll bar to see others. I tried different options online but none of them worked. Can someone help me with it? Thank you!

```html
<div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-3">    
  <input id="Species" type='hidden' name='Species' value=''> 
  <select id="select" class="form-select" aria-label=".form-select example">   
    <option class="option" value="ex" id="ex">Select a Species</option> 
    <option value="1" id="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" id="2">2</option>
    <option value="3" id="3">3</option>
    <option value="4" id="4">4</option> 
    <option value="5" id="5">5</option>
    <option value="6" id="6">6</option>
    <option value="7" id="7">7</option>
    <option value="8" id="8">8</option>  
    <option value="9" id="9">9</option>
    <option value="10" id="10">10</option>
    <option value="11" id="11">11</option>                                                           
    <option value="12" id="12">12</option>
    <option value="13" id="13">13</option>
    <option value="14" id="14">14</option> 
    <option value="15" id="15">15</option>
    <option value="16" id="16">16</option>
    <option value="17" id="17">17</option>
    <option value="18" id="18">18</option>  
    <option value="19" id="19">19</option>
    <option value="20" id="20">20</option>
    <option value="21" id="21">21</option>
    <option value="22" id="22">22</option>
    <option value="23" id="23">23</option>  
    <option value="24" id="24">24</option>
    <option value="25" id="25">25</option>
  </select>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="autocomplete" name="Keyword" placeholder="Type something" data-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"> 
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="search" value="submit">Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You will have to implement your own solution. You cannot use the `<select>` tag for this since the browser picks what is the best for it. If the screen is small though, it will have a scrollbar.

Comment: I have seen much longer select elements, especially with country lists. They always scroll, just when they reach the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Just a general word of warning: Please beware that replacing native controls with custom ones always comes with caveats. First and foremost they might not be usable by people with disabilities and lack features like keyboard or touch control. select2 seems pretty solid, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this and style it but its too much to do so what would i suggest you use this library it also will give you option to search

https://select2.org/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown').select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-3">
    <input id="Species" type='hidden' name='Species' value=''>
    <select id="select" class="form-select dropdown" aria-label=".form-select example">
        <option class="option" value="ex" id="ex">Select a Species</option>
        <option value="1" id="1">1</option>
        <option value="2" id="2">2</option>
        <option value="3" id="3">3</option>
        <option value="4" id="4">4</option>
        <option value="5" id="5">5</option>
        <option value="6" id="6">6</option>
        <option value="7" id="7">7</option>
        <option value="8" id="8">8</option>
        <option value="9" id="9">9</option>
        <option value="10" id="10">10</option>
        /// there are 25 options here in total///

    </select>
    
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="autocomplete" name="Keyword" placeholder="Type something"
        data-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="search" value="submit">Search</button>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-3">
    <input id="Species" type='hidden' name='Species' value=''>
    <select id="select" onfocus='this.size=5;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'
        class="form-select" aria-label=".form-select example">
        <option class="option" value="ex" id="ex">Select a Species</option>
        <option value="1" id="1">1</option>
        <option value="2" id="2">2</option>
        <option value="3" id="3">3</option>
        <option value="4" id="4">4</option>
        <option value="5" id="5">5</option>
        <option value="6" id="6">6</option>
        <option value="7" id="7">7</option>
        <option value="8" id="8">8</option>
        <option value="9" id="9">9</option>
        <option value="10" id="10">10</option>
        /// there are 25 options here in total///

    </select>
    
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="autocomplete" name="Keyword" placeholder="Type something"
        data-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="search" value="submit">Search</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey use `size=5` props in select tag and it would work as you are expecting and you will have 5 options visible and then there will be a vertical scroll bar to scroll for more options. For example :-

```
<select id="select" size="5" class="form-select" aria-label=".form-select example">   
  <option class="option" value="ex" id="ex" >Select a Species</option> 
  <option value="1" id="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" id="2">2</option>
  <option value="3" id="3">3</option>
  <option value="4" id="4">4</option> 
  <option value="5" id="5">5</option>
  <option value="6" id="6">6</option>
  <option value="7" id="7">7</option>
  <option value="8" id="8">8</option>  
  <option value="9" id="9">9</option>
  <option value="10" id="10">10</option>
  /// there are 25 options here in total///
</select>
```

Comment: I tried the size option but it enlarge the select area which make it larger than the input area on the same line.

Comment: can you please add it to the question so i can reproduce and fix the same

Comment: This is a vertical select box, not a drop-down box.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <select id="select" class="form-select" aria-label=".form-select example" onfocus='this.size=11;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'>
       <option class="option" value="ex" id="ex" >Select a Species</option> 
       <option value="1" id="1">1</option>
       <option value="2" id="2">2</option>
       <option value="3" id="3">3</option>
       <option value="4" id="4">4</option> 
       <option value="5" id="5">5</option>
       <option value="6" id="6">6</option>
       <option value="7" id="7">7</option>
       <option value="8" id="8">8</option>  
       <option value="9" id="9">9</option>
       <option value="10" id="10">10</option>
       <option value="11" id="11">11</option> 
       <option value="12" id="12">12</option> 
       <option value="13" id="12">13</option> 
       <!-- and so on... -->
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! "Try this" answers are not useful. Please provide an explanation and link some sources. Please actually answer the question. Read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

`<select size="5"></select>`

does what you need, as it limits the number of options to be displayed and adds a scroll bar if the `select` has more options than specified by `size`. Read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_size.asp

Comment: This makes it a completely different select, not a drop-down. This doesn't answer the question. By the way, please link sources, explain the code, provide an example with the preview code block and provide answers WITH their code.